# Livewallpaper launch from App Icon

Tags: android, xml, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to launch my live wallpaper from the app icon & live wallpaper list. It works from the live list but from the app icon it breaks.

Following is the code for both of them:

```
    <service
        android:label="@string/appName"
        android:name=".LiveService"        
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"
        >

        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not start a WallPaperService yourself.
The system manages all the calls to your service and therefor you engine.
There currently isn't a way to have your wallpaper running as an "app."

The current fix seems to be to have an icon install on the desktop that directs them to the live wallpaper list.